# Pythonpath issue - Cocos2d

Tags: python, pythonpath, cocos2d-python

I'm trying to use a game library called Cocos2d in python. However, I can't really import it. It's installed in one of python's lib directories, and when I import it, it's saying that it's not there. I know it has to do with pythonpath (provided in the IDE I'm using) but I'm not sure how to set it up. I've tried just adding the folder with cocos2d to the python path but it doesn't appear to work. The file's name is not cocos nor are there any files in the same directory with said name. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get an import error message ?

I don't know how you installed it but here are the steps I just did and which are working here.

- Download [cocos2d-0.4.0.zip](http://los-cocos.googlecode.com/files/cocos2d-0.4.0.zip) from the official website
- Extract it anywhere
- Open a command-line in that folder
- type `python setup.py install`

[image: cocos install]

It even automatically installs pyglet.